# Why two "web.xml" files one for web app and one for tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

Why we have two web.xml files, what is the difference between two?? I have one for my web application and there is also one for TomCat server as well, so what is the difference between two??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web.xml for Tomcat (or any other Servlet container) provides defaults that will be used for all web applications. You can then override these defaults for your applications by adding a web.xml for each web app.

Answer (score 0):

From http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Automatic_Context_Configuration:

> The web application properties listed in conf/web.xml will be
>   processed as defaults for this web application. This is used to
>   establish default mappings (such as mapping the *.jsp extension to the
>   corresponding JSP servlet), and other standard features that apply to
>   all web applications.